# Ingesting large number of data items (files or records) using AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

One of our customers is going to submit about 200,000 data items every 10 minutes and we need to process them and ingest them into a database. They are flexible on how to submit data, either using file (csv or json) or even directly writing into Database. We use AWS as our platform.

What is the best solution for this problem in AWS envrionment?

- Submitting data as files on S3 and then we use SNS and
  SQS to be notified when file submitted and then process them
- Submitting data as messages into Kenisis or AWS MSK(Kafka) and then processing them from Kenisis
- Using AWS Datawarehouse

**More details:**

- We are looking for the cheapest and almost the fastest approach (near
  real time). 15~30 minutes delay from data ingest till data presented in database is acceptable.
- The submitted data can be as CSV or JSON format or any other format
  (we    can ask them to send it in the format we want).
- Each data item   is a    simple time-series value like:

  DateTime, Item, Value

  2021-07-14T11:00:00Z, Device0001, 123.9773
  2021-07-14T11:05:00Z, Device0002, 5656.040
  2021-07-14T11:10:00Z, Device0001, 78.12403

Comment: What is "best" solution? Fastest, cheapest, easiest? You can't have everything, and also you even haven't specified is this fully structured data, unstructured, semi-structured? The size of data and the individual items? Example of data?

Comment: I updated the question with more details.

Comment: Seems like some IoT type of data? Maybe then look at IoT solutions at AWS?

Comment: Look into AWS IoT core

Comment: well! actually we have an IoT time-series database which is not in AWS. developed internally in the organisation but customers need to submit data and then we need to ingest. This is one of th data submission approaches which we have at the moment.